# SwiftUI: How to overlap another view on scroll gesture

Tags: ios, user-interface, swiftui, foreach, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView containing two a two part view. The first part is some text elements and an user image.

The second part is a `ZStack` containing a foreach displaying some rectangles with different colors  overlapping each other.

When the user scrolls up on these rectangles, I want the `ZStack` to move up and cover the first part of the view.

Not sure how to explain this better. I will provide the full code, so you can try it out for yourselves.

```
struct Playground4: View {
    var controlPoint = 0.0
    @State private var bookTags = [
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Adventure", color: "6d7aef"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Drama", color: "c096f2"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Romance", color: "d681b0"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Discover", color: "8ad5e0"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Design", color: "db6446"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Action", color: "e8d272"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "History", color: "8fb1e1"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Recommended", color: "325eb5"),
        
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            
            // PART ONE ---------


            HStack {
                Text("For You")
                    .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .black, design: .rounded))
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
            }
            .padding(30)
            .padding(.bottom, -30)
            
            
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                Text("Book or author")
                    .opacity(0.8)
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .rounded))
                    .kerning(1)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
            }
            .padding(30)
            
            
            
           // PART TWO --------


                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    
                    ForEach(Array(bookTags.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, tag in
//                        CustomCard(controlPoint: controlPoint)
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 300)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex: tag.color))
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: -5, y: -5)
                            .overlay {
                                VStack {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(tag.name)
                                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        
                                        
                                    }
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                                    
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                .padding(.top, 30)
                                
                            } // Overlay
                            .padding(.top, index != 0 ? CGFloat(index) * 75: 0)
                        
                    } // Foreach
                    
                } // Zstack
            }
        } // Scroll
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: To make this compile, I had to add Tag as a simple struct. But I am only seeing the first part. Is there any other code in Tag besides the three properties? You can [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own post.

So I managed to make it scroll over the "first part", like this:

Feel free to come with comments and improvements

```
struct Tag: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let color: String
}


struct Playground4: View {
    var controlPoint = 0.0
    @State private var bookTags = [
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Adventure", color: "6d7aef"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Drama", color: "c096f2"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Romance", color: "d681b0"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Discover", color: "8ad5e0"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Design", color: "db6446"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Action", color: "e8d272"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "History", color: "8fb1e1"),
        Tag(id: UUID(), name: "Recommended", color: "325eb5"),
        
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
      
        ZStack{
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                
                
                HStack {
                    Text("For You")
                        .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .black, design: .rounded))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                }
                .padding(30)
                .padding(.bottom, -30)
                
                
                
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Book or author")
                        .opacity(0.8)
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .rounded))
                        .kerning(1)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                }
                .padding(30)
            }
            .offset(y: -300)
            
            GeometryReader {proxy in
            ScrollView{
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    
                    ForEach(Array(bookTags.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, tag in
//                        CustomCard(controlPoint: controlPoint)
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 300)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex: tag.color))
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: -5, y: -5)
                            .overlay {
                                
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(tag.name)
                                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        
                                        
                                    }
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Image("Book 1")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 100, height: 175)
                                            .cornerRadius(7)
                                        
                                        Image("Book 2")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 100, height: 175)
                                            .cornerRadius(7)
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                            Text("44K+")
                                                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                            
                                            Text("Books")
                                                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                                            
                                            
                                            Spacer()
                                            
                                            
                                        }
                                        .padding(.top)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    }
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                .padding(.top, 30)
                                
                            } // Overlay
                            .padding(.top, index != 0 ? CGFloat(index) * 150: 0)
                        
                    } // Foreach
                    
                } // Zstack
                .offset(y: 200)
                .padding(.bottom, 190)
            }
           
            .frame(height: proxy.size.height)
                
            }
        } // Scroll
       
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this with Xcode 14.3.1, but still only seeing the first ZStack.

Comment: I am using the same Xcode version, so I dont know why that is. I tried running the code again, and it seems to work fine. Maybe make sure dont have any other code interfering.

Comment: Your code is not a [example]. It is missing some images as well as the implementation of `Color(hex: String)`